# Creating elements which match CSS selectors?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

I would like to create a function which allows me to create an element which has a specified CSS path, passed as a string as the first argument.

**Example usage:**

```
createElement('span.top-navigation > div.menuOne > a[target="_blank"]');
```

Should create an element which would always match against that CSS selector.

---

So far, I was thinking to break the selector into its component parts, so classes, id's, children, descendants, etc. And then test against each progressive selector to see if that element exists, eg. given input `span#navigation.align-top > div.menu > div.menuItem` it would test against each of the following

1. `span`------------------------------------------------------------found
2. `span#navigation`--------------------------------------------found
3. `span#navigation.align-top`------------------------------found
4. `span#navigation.align-top > div`---------------------doesn't exist
5. `span#navigation.align-top > div.menu`
6. `span#navigation.align-top > div.menu > div`
7. `span#navigation.align-top > div.menu > div.menuItem`

in turn, to find the first element which doesn't exist.

If, say, item 4 could not be found, then the function would create an element `div` and append it to `span#navigation.align-top`, assign it a class of menu, then create another div element, assign it class `menuItem`, and then append it to the previously created element.

I was just thinking that this seems incredibly complex, there must be an easier, more efficient method of doing this.

Even if there isn't really a much better algorithm/pre-built function, answers which explain how I can improve my current concepts, or warn me of CSS selector oddities, would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

---

### TL;DR

Is there a way to simple create elements based on a CSS path?

Comment: First, you would have to define the css version you are going to use. Then you will have to create a lexical perser for that version of css. This is where regular expressions can help. And then, you would have to do the steps you outlined. Of course, it would be faster to have an internal Map of the current DOM to improve searching, etc. Maybe show us what you have tried so far

Comment: This could create problems by creating divs into elements you don't want those divs getting into.

Comment: @Pinoniq CSS3; Is there not a simpler method though? Like document.querySelector, but for creation? If not, this should go on the JavaScript to-do list. Could you make an answer outlining exactly how you would implement everything you just described?

Comment: @Drifter What does that mean?

Comment: document.querySelector takes a selector string and matches elements against it. There is no standardized API for interfacing with the native selector parser, which is why you will need to implement one yourself in order to get the component selectors that you will need.

Comment: This should go on the JavaScript to-do list? What is the use-case for it?

Comment: @minseong there is an assumption that the first element is always unique by this example. But what if you read out a 'p div.box #uniqueCheck' and it only finds the 'p'? CSS should never be part of the architecture or as an advisor how to build stuff.

Comment: @Drifter I'd thought about that as well, probably just make it direct descendant. And if no tag is specified, assume div.

Comment: @minseong: "if no tag is specified, assume div" That's actually [what Haml does](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#implicit_div_elements).

Comment: @BoltClock HAML is in Ruby where the setup is NOT designed in CSS. I think the idea of the concept is good, only reading out could break a lot of things if you let other people in your code.

Comment: @Drifter: Huh? How is that relevant?

Comment: [Just Use JQuery](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif)

Comment: @BoltClock Reading back my comment, I meant that doing it the way HAML does is good, instead of CSS notation or using a css-file as reference.

Comment: @minseong Mootools framework uses something very similar that you're looking for. When creating a new Element then you can pass an entire CSS-path, just as you'd like, in order to create said element in a specific position. Please see http://mootools.net/core/docs/1.5.2/Element/Element#Element:constructor

Comment: @kunambi Would you like to add a more detailed version of that comment as an answer? It seems just what I need...

Comment: @minseong As you can see at http://jsfiddle.net/ypqL7xu3/ it wont create more elements than the first one you're specifying. However, I was thinking that if you override the constructor and/or use new Element together with Slick (http://mootools.net/core/docs/1.5.2/Slick/Slick), then you'll probably be able to create just what you want.